# Is it possible to do a css transition from one value to another when applying a class?

Tags: css

I have a transition attribute like this:

```
transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
```

Initially, the element has no transform attribute.

Is it possible to apply a class that allows you to first set one transform-attribute and then transition to another attribute (I know I could do it by applying two classes after each other, but that is not practical in this scenario):

```
transform: translate3d(0,750px,0);
```

to

```
transform: translate3d(0,100vh,0);
```

Comment: You can use keyframe animation css3 https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: That's really helpful, but I want to use the values from transition to perform the transition(the values are updated, and also I'm not sure how to do an cubic-beizer-curve with keyframes)

Comment: That is something you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/aQZFF/4/?

Comment: Isn't that the entire point of transitions?

Comment: @BoltClock what is?

Comment: @TanDuong amazing, didn't know that's how it works!

Comment: Transitioning from one value to another when you apply a class or some other selector.

Comment: yes, but I want to first set a value and then transition from that value to another, turns out you can do that with animations.